# Adding events on mouseover, how do you add an event only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event listener, that works like this (pseudo code):

```
canvas.onmousemove = function (e) { checkCollision(e); };

var checkCollision = function(e){
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var coordinates = getMouseXY();

    // draw any shape with the context

    if(context.isPointInPath(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y){
          $(canvas).on('click', alertFunction, e);
          return; //stop the function from doing anything else
    }

    $(canvas).off('click', alertFunction, e);      
};

var alertFunction = function(e){
    alert("this alert should only show once per click");
};
```

My expected result: when I hover over a specific line drawn in canvas, I can click to get an alert.

Actual result: when I click my line in the canvas, I get a lot of alerts. My guess: for every pixel that I move over the element, the click listener gets added. So the alert will play a lot of times if I hover over the element. If I hover outside the element, one event listener will be removed for every pixel I move outside the element.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It seems you're binding the click event handler inside a function that is called multiple times, so the event handler is added again and again.

Comment: not sure if I understood but maybe you want to use jQuery's [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function instead of `on`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about if you change like so?

```
canvas.onmousemove = function (e) { checkCollision(e); };

var checkCollision = function(e){
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var coordinates = getMouseXY();

    // draw any shape with the context

    if(context.isPointInPath(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y){
          $(canvas).off().on('click', alertFunction, e);
          return; //stop the function from doing anything else
    }
};

var alertFunction = function(e){
    alert("this alert should only show once per click");
};
```

Comment: Thanks, simply removing the event and re-adding it works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hover()` function:

```js
$('div').hover(function() {
  alert('hoverd');
}, function() {
  alert('out of div');
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hover</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a one method that lets you attach the event to the event handler only once.
http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "mouseover", function() {
     checkCollision();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like it would be better for you to remove the onmousemove and put all your code in an on click.

Within the onclick add the if isPointInPath function and alertFucntion if true, otherwise do nothing.

```
$(canvas).click(function() {
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var coordinates = getMouseXY();

   if(context.isPointInPath(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y){
      alertFunction(e);
      return; //stop the function from doing anything else
   }
})
```

Onmouseover fires every time your mouse moves 1 pixel on your canvas so it's not ideal for binding another function.

If you absolutely must do it this way check if there's already a bind on your element

```
$.data(!$(canvas).get(0), 'events' ).click) {
   $(canvas).on('click',alertfucntion, e}
}
```

or something like this...

The other comment with .off() might work; and I could be mistaken; but I think it is removing all your binds then rebinding the click() for every pixel you move, which might result in a lot of performance issues later on, perhaps?